# LUA String phrase match

Tags: lua, openresty

string: `x11y22z33`

I want to validate above value with string.match with 1 string and 2 numbers

```
string.match(s,"/^\s{1}\d{2}\s{1}\d{2}\s{1}\d{2}")
```

I tried but it didn't work

Answer (score 3):

`Lua` has a specific syntax for that:

```
string.match(s,"(%a)(%d%d)(%a)(%d%d)(%a)(%d%d)")
```

You can look in the manual in the chapter `5.4.1 – Patterns`

http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html

Answer (score 1):

Also `string.find()` can handle patterns and gives you the position...
( `:` means: The datatype "string" has `string` metamethods )

```
do
local str='not important important: x11y22z33 and ignore rest'
local head,tail,a,b,c=str:find('(%a%d%d)(%a%d%d)(%a%d%d)')

print(str:sub(head,tail))

return head,tail,a,b,c
end
```

( Without errorhandling )
...to extract it with `string.sub()`
Output and result (return) is...

```
x11y22z33
26  34  x11 y22 z33
```

Above example also shows that the result of `string.find()` is extended when `()` is used.
So the pattern `(%a)(%d+)(%a)(%d+)(%a)(%d+)` resulting in 3 key/value pairs.

```
local head,tail,k1,x,k2,y,k3,z=str:find('(%a)(%d+)(%a)(%d+)(%a)(%d+)')
...
return head,tail,k1,x,k2,y,k3,z 
-- Puts out: 26 34 x 11 y 22 z 33
-- And also works with x1024y3000z5
```